# How come the ternary is not compiled to the same assembly as if?

Tags: c, ternary-operator

I have two files:

```
int PolyMod(int s);
void CreateChecksum(int isTestNet, int *mod) {
    *mod = PolyMod(isTestNet == 0 ? 5 : 9);
}
```

and

```
int PolyMod(int s);
void CreateChecksum(int isTestNet, int *mod) {
    if (isTestNet == 0) {
        *mod = PolyMod(5);
    } else {
        *mod = PolyMod(9);
    }
}
```

Somehow their assembly result is different. Why? You can see the assembly created from the [first file here](https://godbolt.org/g/DLTs3N) and from [the second file here](https://godbolt.org/g/qBDi6F).

Doesn't the compiler know that they're equivalent, and one is faster? Was the reason they had different assemblies was that they're exactly equally fast, and the only difference between them was the order of operations?

I've wondered if the difference was caused by static branch prediction. After experimenting with `__builtin_expect`, I believe that the answer is no.

Comment: I'd say the compiler doesn't know that the call in the `else` in the second piece of code is identical to the statement in the `if`. Or is that naive?

Comment: The difference is due to the code skeleton used by the compiler for the different constructs, try the second using the optimizations (see https://godbolt.org/g/9VcAfp), and you'll find an even shorter code.

Comment: The code is different. A ternary operator is not the same as an if statement.Therefore optimizations are applied in different ways/orders. Expecting an identical result doesn't seem to be reasonable.

Comment: For the interested: the ternary operator version doesn't even have a conditional branch with optimizations turned on: https://godbolt.org/g/LhmTvm

Comment: The ternary version also doesn't have any branches if compiled by clang with O0. They both yield the same asm with no branches if compiled with clang with 03. I'll report this to GCC as missed optimization.

Comment: The difference is substantially due to **side effects**. A ternary operator can have a single side effect, while an `if`/`else` can have at least a couple if not more. The compiler preserve this with a different implementation duplicating code to allow for side effects to happen. Anyway in this case a strongly optimized compiler would have outputted same code.

Comment: @joop The standard explicitly says that the conditional operator does have a sequence point between the evaluation of the 1st and 2nd/3rd operand. You can kind of regard the `?` as the sequence point.

Comment: Which optimization options do you pass to the compiler?

Comment: The equivalent if-else version would rather be: `int param; if(isTestNet == 0) { param = 5; } else { param = 9; } *mod = PolyMod(param)`. Sure, logically it is the same thing, but the compiler might not necessarily think the same way as humans do.

Comment: Compilers are stupider than most people expect, and miss a lot of optimization opportunities. Though in this case, clang does generate the same branchless assembly code for both versions.

Comment: Note: never compare gcc -O0 code. Use at least -Os or -O2. Note2: -Os and -O2 still give different code but differently different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the problem is a *missed optimization* bug, caused by GIMPLE in GCC. Clang doesn't have this bug, so it generates the same assembly.

I've reported this to GCC; the bug can be tracked here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85971

Comment: Don't forget that you can accept your own answer two days after posting the question.

Answer (score 1):

C does not impose any restriction about what instructions to generate in hardware.

It is allowed to generate any possible instruction as time as the semantics of the generated code remains the same as the abstract semantics of C (defined in ISO 9899).

The compiler will transform the C code in many intermediate languages(combinators, rtl, ssa, generic, gimple, etc etc), in particular in RTL and from there there is generated hardware dependent code.

You should study the intermediate languages in order to understand why the generated assembler is different.